# Get absolute path of FILE in WiX

Tags: windows, wix, registry

I got the following file in WiX:

```
<Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='91C8C2C0-59AF-4BDD-A78D-C4369DD4CD81'>
  <File Id='FoobarEXE' Name='FoobarAppl10.exe' Source='FoobarAppl10.exe' KeyPath='yes'>
  </File>
</Component>
```

---

```
<Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="D3B0871E-A86D-4692-B419-AE2A2A578648">
  <RegistryValue Root='HKCR' Key='conversationwindowaction\shell\open\command' Type='string' Value='"[absolute path to exe]" "%1"' KeyPath='yes' />
</Component>
```

I want [absolute path to exe] be the string to the path of FoobarEXE, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
<Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="D3B0871E-A86D-4692-B419-AE2A2A578648">
  <RegistryValue Root='HKCR' Key='conversationwindowaction\shell\open\command' Type='string' Value='"[#FoobarEXE]" "%1"' KeyPath='yes' />
</Component>
```

You need to enclose the file id in `[#fileid]` see example above.